# Salesforce Custom Notifications Url - REST API

Tags: notification, push-notification

Hi Does anyone know what API or Query can be used to get what the notifications have been raised for a user? based on the new notification framework.

I can see an API to raise notifications I can also see ways to query the existing notification types, but no way for us to query the notifications that have been raised for a user.

Comment: There are a few sObjects that may help here, but I haven't used PushNotifications directly to test them. Have a look at `MobilePushDevice`, `MobilePushUserUpdate`, `AndroidPushApplicationSetup`, `MobilePushServiceDevice`, `ApplePushApplicationSetup`, `MobilePushSetupRegistry`

Comment: Thanks, @DanielBallinger, I will take a look. I doubt if these are used by the new Notifications framework. I want to avoid roll my own custom notifications framework to be able to query the notifications for a user.